# ExceptionHandler in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
import org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException;
import javax.annotation.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/aa")
public class BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/bb/{number}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "plain/text")
    public void test(@PathVariable final double number, final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        throw new MyException("whatever");
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
    public MyError handleMyException(final MyException exception, final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        ...
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(TypeMismatchException.class)
    public MyError handleTypeMismatchException(final TypeMismatchException exception, final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        ...
    }

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler
    public MyError handleException(final Exception exception) throws IOException {
        ...
    }
}
```

If I call http://example.com/aa/bb/20
the function handleMyException is executed, as expected.

However, if I call http://example.com/aa/bb/QQQ
I would expect that the function `handleTypeMismatchException` is called,
but instead, handleException is called, with exception of type `TypeMismatchException`.

a nasty workaround to make it would would be to test the type of exception inside `handleException()`,
and call `handleTypeMismatchException` if the exception is of type `TypeMismatchException`.

but why does it now work?
the exceptionhandler is chosen at runtime according to the type of exception?
or it is chosen at compile time?

Comment: what is the exception thrown in the case of `http://example.com/aa/bb/QQQ`

Comment: function handleException(final Exception exception) is being called with exception being an instance of TypeMismatchException.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract from [official spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler):

> You use the @ExceptionHandler method annotation within a controller to
>   specify which method is invoked when an exception of a specific type
>   is thrown during the **execution of controller methods**

Exception you're trying to catch is generated by spring itself(string-to-double convertion), before actual method execution. Catching it is not in spec of @ExceptionHandler. That does make sense - typically you wouldn't want to catch exceptions generated by framework itself.

Comment: So does Spring offer any alternatives for this specific case?